# Improving a method by using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Is there a better way of writing the following method? Using LINQ maybe?
Instead of declaring a new list and then using a foreach to populate the list, is there a better way of doing this maybe in one line using LINQ?

```
public IEnumerable<RoleAreasModel> GetRolesWithRoleAreasModelByUserGUID(Guid guid)
    {
      IList<RoleAreasModel> rolesWithRoleAreas = new List<RoleAreasModel>();
      foreach (AspnetRolesRecord role in GetByUserGUID(guid))
      {
        RoleAreasRecord roleAreaRecord = RoleAreasService.Instance.GetRecord(RoleAreasRecord.Fields.ID, role.ID);
        rolesWithRoleAreas.Add(new RoleAreasModel(roleAreaRecord.Area, new RolesMapper().MapToModel(role), getAreaControllersData(roleAreaRecord.ID)));
      }
      return rolesWithRoleAreas;
    }
```

Comment: Why do you want to convert 7 readable lines to 1 unreadable line?

Comment: Using ReSharper, I've seen automatic suggestions to these kind of code to replace by link. Most of the times, it was less readable to me (maybe due to lack of experience).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public IEnumerable<RoleAreasModel> Foo(Guid id)
{
   var mapper = new RolesMapper();
   return from role in GetByUserGUID(id)
          let areaRecord = RoleAreasService.Instance.GetRecord(RoleAreasRecord.Fields.ID, role.ID)
          select new RoleAreasModel(areaRecord.Area, mapper.MapToModel(role), getAreaControllersData(areaRecord.ID));
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Since you return an `IEnumerable<RoleAreasModel>`, use [yield return](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx) rather than creating a temporary list:

```
public IEnumerable<RoleAreasModel> GetRolesWithRoleAreasModelByUserGUID(Guid guid)
{
    foreach (AspnetRolesRecord role in GetByUserGUID(guid))
    {
        RoleAreasRecord roleAreaRecord = RoleAreasService.Instance.GetRecord(RoleAreasRecord.Fields.ID, role.ID);
        yield return new RoleAreasModel(roleAreaRecord.Area, new RolesMapper().MapToModel(role), getAreaControllersData(roleAreaRecord.ID));
    }
}
```

By the way, Eric Lippert wrote a very interesting series of blog posts about iterators and how they work in C#. They are *very* much worth a read.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/iterator-blocks-part-one

Comment: Why do you use iterators and not LINQ?

Comment: @AS-CII: Linq returns an iterator as well.  It just provides syntactic sugar on top of the iterator, sometimes with a significant performance overhead.

Comment: I'm still busy learning LINQ and converting old iterators to LINQ. Thanks for the help

Comment: I didn't downvote you :) I know LINQ is built on top of iterators but using them this way seems like reinventing the wheel to me: with LINQ you achieve the same results writing more readable code!

Comment: @AS-CII: Didn't mean you specifically with the downvote :-)  I don't really agree that the Linq version is more readable.  I think that depends entirely on the reader's comfort with Linq vs. iterators.

Comment: @AS-CII: The great thing with this answer is that we (as the readers) can't be too sure on the overhead of you `RoleAreasRecord` class or the `RolesMapper` class. The `yield` will only execute an on demand scenario, which would be better than querying all of the records and then you only using one. Good work @Eric J. ;-)

Comment: @DominicZukiewicz That's true also for LINQ version since it uses yield internally.

Comment: Both links are broken. The first redirects to some main page (`https://devblogs.microsoft.com/`) and for the second the result is `Service Unavailable - DNS failure`.

Comment: Perhaps delete the last part of the answer if replacements can not be found? (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar (this is what the revision history is for) - the answer should appear as if it was written today). )

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
public IEnumerable<RoleAreasModel> GetRolesWithRoleAreasModelByUserGUID(Guid guid)
{
  return GetByUserGUID(guid).Select( role =>
    {
      var roleAreaRecord = RoleAreasService.Instance.GetRecord(RoleAreasRecord.Fields.ID, role.ID);
      return new RoleAreasModel(roleAreaRecord.Area, new RolesMapper().MapToModel(role),getAreaControllersData(roleAreaRecord.ID)));
    });
}
```